# data is not updating immediately from server in react js

Tags: reactjs, node.js, server, axios

I have a `/home` route in this route I've fetched all my posts and passed the data into the `<Post />` component now in the post component there is a like button that the user can click to like or dislike and with it into likes array all the id of whom liked are stored in my node server. beside the like button I've fetched all likes count. the moment I click on the like the `likes.length` is not updating on the spot when I re-render my post it works fine but it's a very bad approach I think is any better solution for it

full client code :

```
const { image, _id, caption, owner,likes } = post;
const likeHandler = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/post/${_id}`);
    if (data.liked) {
      setLike(data.liked);
      toast.success("Post liked");
    }
    if (!data.liked) {
      setLike(false);
      toast.success("Post unliked!");
    }
  };
```

Here im getting my length:

```
<Popover>
        <PopoverTrigger>{likes.length}</PopoverTrigger>
        <PopoverContent>
          <div className="flex items-center justify-between mb-2">
            <div className="flex items-center gap-x-2">
              <div className="img w-10 h-10 bg-blue-500 rounded-full"></div>
              <div className="owner_name font-semibold">John Doe</div>
            </div>
            <Button className="bg-blue-400 rounded text-white">
              <TbMoodPlus />
            </Button>
          </div>
        </PopoverContent>
      </Popover>
```

Here's the server code:

```
export const likedAndDisLikedPost = async (req, res) => {
  try {

    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);

    if (!post) {
        res.status(404).send({ success: false, message: "Post not found.." })
    }
    if (post.likes.includes(req.user._id)) {
        const index = await post.likes;
        post.likes.splice(index, 1);
        await post.save();
        return res.status(200).send({ success: true, message: "post unliked", liked: false })
    }
    else {

        await post?.likes?.push(req.user._id);
        await post.save()
        res.status(200).send({ success: true, message: "Post Liked", liked: true });
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send({ success: false, message: "Opps something went wrong.." })
  }
}
```

Comment: Without the client and server source codes, no one can help you.

Comment: There is not enough code to identify the problem, share a stack-blitz of the code or the full code for the Home and Post Component

Comment: suppose you wite a post and its a post request to the server now you want to see to immedietly after posting how to do this?
simply with react re render or refresh the page?

Comment: Your server, after processing a change request, can return the full modified record
which will contain the current likes counter.

Answer (score 0):

Use useEffect for checking whether the previous state has changed but this step can be hectic and boring , the most preferable method is by using redux in your react app , create a store and with all the data you need , then just get the data or dispatch actions as per your need , One more solution for you can be just reload after the operation but this is not good

> So in the end
> I'd suggest you to use any state management library , it can be anything that you are most comfortable with

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).